# Error after Upgrading access ADP to Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, adp

I'm trying to upgrade my access ADP to Access 2013 Aadc using linked tables. But when running this code

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstbks As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
Set rstbks = New ADODB.Recordset
Select Case Me!pub_tabctrl.Value
     Case 0      
        With rstbks
            Set .ActiveConnection = cn
            .Source = "select vendor, telephone, city from neelwafu.vendors where vendorcode=" & txtpublisher
            .LockType = adLockOptimistic
            .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
```

I get this error
error: couldnt find file c:\user\user\documents\xxx.mdb
What could be causing this?

Comment: Just to be sure, your real code actually compiles, right? as it stands you have an missing `End With` and a missing `End Select`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error because the ability to open ADP files in Access 2013 has been [`fully removed`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-access-2013-HA102749226.aspx)

Microsoft's recommended solution (from the above link) is that

> Access 2013 SQL-based databases will replace much of the benefit of ADPs.